# How to add Item to JList from a different Class

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, jlist

There are two classes: A and B.

Class A has an empty JList.
Class B has a JButton.

So I want to add an string to the list when I press the button.  I got the layout, but the problem is in passing the item.

Can someone code it in a simple way please??

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @MrD Ok i'll posy my code in a separate answer ;)

Comment: No you shouldn't this question is a duplicate.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Its the same question basically but I decided to add this post without my own code cuz I thought it was complicated, as you attempted to answer but did not work.  So in here maybe someone can code it in his/her own way but with the same functionality.

Comment: @AlexJj: It's not personal.  You asked the same question twice.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc lol did you read my last comment? repeating again. YES I asked the same question but this time i'm not asking to complete my code. Just wanna see how people can solve it in their own way.